# Load Knockout Observable with stored value from localStorage

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I do this? I tried to do it with an extender I built based on the code here: https://github.com/jimrhoskins/knockout.localStorage

It saves the value to localStorage just fine, however upon reloading the page, Knockout seems to ignore the set value and overrides it with the first option from the array.

```
<select data-bind="value: pageSize, options: search_filter_data.page_sizes, optionsText: 'label'"></select>

page_sizes: [{
        value: 10,
        label: '10 Per Page'
    }, {
        value: 25,
        label: '25 Per Page'
    }, {
        value: 50,
        label: '50 Per Page'
    }, {
        value: 9999,
        label: 'All'
    }]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `pageSize`? Does their example work for you when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Use ***optionsValue*** property like in this example :

> Example : http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/kA8W3/

```
<select data-bind="value: pageSize, options: page_sizes,
        optionsText: 'label', optionsValue: 'value' "></select>

function ViewModel() {

    this.page_sizes =  [{       
        value: 10,
        label: '10 Per Page'
    }, {        
        value: 25,
            label: '25 Per Page'
    }, {
        value: 50,
        label: '50 Per Page'
    }, {       
        value: 9999,
        label: 'All'
    }]; 

    this.pageSize = ko.observable(25);

};

$(function() {  

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 


})​
```